# lastpage package: incompatibility with nameref package

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, lastpage

When I try to use the [nameref package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nameref) together with the [lastpage package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) (version earlier than 2013/01/28, of course) I have following two errors:

```
! Package lastpage Error: no auxiliary file allowed
! Extra \else
```

But without the *nameref* package (and referencing chapters by names) my LaTeX document builds without problems.
What does this error mean? And what are possible causes?

My document file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\onehalfspacing
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
Text.
%\input{./title.tex}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
    \fancyhf{}
        \fancyfoot[C]{Strona \normalsize\thepage\ z \pageref{LastPage}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove line between header and main text
}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\pagestyle{plain}
Text.
%\input{./ch1.tex}
%\input{./ch2.tex}
%\input{./ch3.tex}
%\input{./ch4.tex}
%\input{./biblio.tex}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reasons, `nameref` and `lastpage` fight each other when trying to do something to the `.aux` file just before finishing.

All works if you say

```
\usepackage{zref-user,zref-lastpage}
```

instead of `\usepackage{lastpage}` and

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\normalsize Strona \thepage\ z \zpageref{LastPage}}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove line between header and main text
}
```

Note the command `\zpageref`. (Also `\normalsize` should go before `Strona`).

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: "For some reasons, nameref and lastpage fight each other when trying to do something to the .aux file just before finishing." Well, the reason was a little bit different (see my answer), but `zref-lastpage` works, of course.

Answer (score 3):

**Since [`lastpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) 2012/01/28 v1.2l the incompatibility with [`nameref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nameref) is fixed.**

The `nameref` package redefines `\label` to have five arguments instead of two, therefore

```
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{\thepage}{}{}{}}
```

instead of

```
\newlabel{LastPage}{{}{\thepage}}
```

must be used in the `lastpage` package, when also `nameref` is used in the document. (When `nameref` and [`hyperref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) were both used, there was no problem, because `hyperref` uses another label format, which was already regarded by `lastpage`.)

Using `lastpage` since version 1.2l, 2013/01/28, your MWE works without any problem.

Thanks for reporting the incompatibility! (See at Acknowledgements and History in the package's documentation.)